# NG Zorro vs normal css styling for a we developer

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, ng-zorro-antd

We are using ngzorro (angular third party material) in our project. The project is almost halfway through. We face some issues in customizing styles. Management asking whether we can continue with ng zorro or style using normal CSS.

Can anyone please suggest at this point which is good? Following ngzorro or designing using your own CSS.

My project is completely done so far using ngzorro. My project involves various forms and charts. Also please tell me the drawbacks of using angular materials instead of styling using normal CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the style of ngZorro where I could. In some cases where it was needed like:

- text color of enabled and disabled elements
- background color of enabled and disabled elements
- width and height
- margin and padding
- own icons and text

I applied some own css rules.

As always it depends on the complexity of your project and given design. Regarding my experience I remember that applying your my own CSS rules was easy to accomplish and not that time consuming.

Regarding the drawbacks...
Using angular material design and defining you're own css classes is no contradiction. Thanks to angular material and it's friends I'm not in the pressure of reinventing the wheel. It's well thought out and went though a lot of dev stages my own CSS would need to go it self. I rather like to extend the given design where it is needed.